# How to treat all the file in the directory in for loop batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to do the command `jhove -m PDF-hul -h xml -o C:\Users\N\test.xml %%a` for each file in the directory through for loop. The problem is that only one last file from the directory will be processed. This is my code:

```
@echo off

for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s C:\Users\N\test\') do (

jhove -m PDF-hul -h xml -o C:\Users\N\test.xml %%a

)


pause
```

Comment: Are you sure only the last file is processed?  It looks like jhove overwrites test.xml every time.  I believe there might be a "process whole directory" option to jhove.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen    when I'm doing echo %%a I get all the files shown. But I see that in the cmd output that jhove is processing only the last pdf file. There's no such option in jhove to process the whole directory that' s why I' trying to do it with loop for and also I need separate text.xml output for every processed pdf.

Comment: How do you see in the cmd output that jhove is processing the last pfd file only?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  Yes, you are right that test.xml is overwritten every time. Just checked that.

Comment: You most likely want to create the output filename so it is unique for each file processed.

Answer (score -1):

Your loop is setup to loop through a text file by using the /f option. I think if you drop that option, it should properly access each file during that loop.

See below for change:

```
for %%a in ('dir /b /s C:\Users\N\test\') do (

jhove -m PDF-hul -h xml -o C:\Users\N\test.xml %%a

)
```

Comment: The /F option of the `FOR` command also allows you to capture the output of a command surrounded by single quotes.  So the /F is needed.  But you are on the right track.  Just use a standard `FOR` command but just list the directory in the IN clause of the FOR command.  No need for the DIR command.